# jQuery: Control page reloads or moving away from the current page

Tags: jquery, browser, user-interaction

If a user moves away from the current page by using mouse (clicking on a link) or keyboard (hitting enter while having a form element focused) interactions, i want to do be able to run JavaScript/jQuery commands beforehand.

Exemplary workflow:

1. User clicks on any link or hits a key which will result in loading a new page in the browser
2. A JavaScript event gets fired and does something (for example `console.log()`)
3. Finally, the page load is executed

Furthermore, it would be great if that also works with user events that trigger a page reload (like pressing F5).

I realize that there is something similar here on Stackoverflow. It shows an alert before loading another page if there is unsaved content in an answer box. That may be the same functionality i ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
 return "Handler for .unload() called.";
});
```

Reference: [JQuery unload()](http://api.jquery.com/unload/).

Comment: So simple yet powerful. Thanks alot!

Comment: You dont necessarily need jQuery Unload. Native Javascript supports the onUnload event